# Are there any Dropdown controls with checkboxes in them?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, checkbox

I've seen some for web using javascript, but I am looking for a Windows Form control that is a ComboBox that when opened displays a list of checkboxes and labels, allowing to select one or more, with a "Select All" option.

Would like a non-commercial solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to suggest a commercial solution, however, I am using the [DevExpress Winforms suite](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/) and it has exactly what you are looking for.  Plus it really let's you really customize it (as you see in the example below).

[image]

Comment: It's exactly what I am looking for, but I am unable to use any commercial solution per company policy.

Comment: @esac, I have to say that it's a dumb policy. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: It has to do with liability. We can control our code, and if a bug occurs that causes a customer to lose business, data, etc.. we can work with them, escalate it, and get it solved and get a fix to them. Have you ever tried getting a bug fixed in somebody else's software product? First they have to repro it, then they have to acknowledge its a bug, then they have to find the cause, then develop a solution, then test it out, then package it up, and if they are a good company they submit it to you right away, otherwise you have to wait for a new release.

Comment: DevExpress is around now, but will they be around in 5 years when we are still supporting our products? 10 years?

Comment: @esac.  When you buy their product, you have the option to also buy the code.  You can also, of course, just reflector their binaries.

Answer (score 0):

why can't you build your own checked comboBox by integrating a label, button and a checked listbox?